# How to get two different markers on Google map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails2

gmaps4rails 2 + rails 4 + ruby 2.0

```
<script>
        handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
        handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @geo_hash.to_json %>);
        });
        handler.map.centerOn({ lat: <%= raw @geo_city[0][:lat] %>, lng: <%=raw @geo_city[0][:lng] %> })
        handler.getMap().setZoom(7)

    </script>
```

- @geo_hash = [{:lat=>16.9916,
    :lng=>81.7838,
    :infowindow=>"railway station",
    :picture=>{:url=>"/assets/web/**blank_red.png**", :width=>32, :height=>32},
    :title=>"abc temple"}
    ]
- @geo_city  = [{:lat=>15.8273,
    :lng=>78.047,
    :infowindow=>"Bus stand",
    :picture=>{:picture=>"/assets/web/**blank.png", :width=>32, :height=>32},
    :title=>"A.S. Peta"}]

I want two different marker on Google map but only one marker is coming ? any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution...

```
<script>
        handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
        handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        markers1 = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @geo_hash.to_json %>);
        markers2 = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @geo_city.to_json %>);
        });
        handler.map.centerOn({ lat: <%= raw @geo_city[0][:lat] %>, lng: <%=raw @geo_city[0][:lng] %> })
        handler.getMap().setZoom(7)

    </script>
```

Thanks.